# Curl Php Returns NULL in browser on

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml, curl

I am trying to authenticate to third party ticketing system, connect and retrieve agent info. I then want to parse retrieved file so as to only show specific info such as 'id' and' 'active_since', but I get an NULL error in browser. Any help?

FILE RETURNED BY THIRDPARTY

```
[agent] => Array
        (
            [active_since] => 2015-11-30T08:09:26-01:00
            [available] => 1
            [created_at] => 2015-05-14T19:15:18+00:00
            [id] => XXXXX 
            [occasional] => 
            [points] => 5520
            [scoreboard_level_id] => 5000402007
            [signature] => 
            [signature_html] =>
```

Below is the PHP CURL code.

```
 <?php
    $username = "xxxxxxx";
    $password = "xxxxxxx";
    $url = 'http://support.xxxx.com/agents/xxx132067';

    $cURL = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
    curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Accept: application/json',
        'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")      

    )
    );

    $result = file_get_contents($url);
    // Will dump a beauty json :3
    var_dump(json_decode($result, true));

    $array["active_since"];

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `'header' =>` from the `Authorization` header. And it should be as below:

```
"Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("$username:$password")
```

And I didn't see you are calling curl at all. Replace your `file_get_contents` with proper curl call.

```
$result = curl_exec($cURL);
curl_close($cURL);
```

Comment: I don't get the NULL error but I am still not able to only fetch the active since section... Just get whole page in json format.